# CSS problem with divs and inline components

Tags: css

Imagine a code like this:

```css
.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

It will render something like this:

[image: Descriptive Image]

I want that the blue div comes up and stay on the right of the red div. Imagine that I can´t change the divs from where they are, so I need to do it in css. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the markup, if you set `float: left` to the red `<div>` then you could put the blue `<div>` to its right side

```css
.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution which uses `float` on the red div works well, but here is another possible solution:

Apply `position: relative;` to the blue div (to be able to move it in relation to its default position) and add `top: -100px; left: 100px;` to move it up next to the red div:

```css
.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with the `grid` CSS.  Here I used a named template `box` and then in the "chatty verbose" CSS I put the positional related for each "block".  I added classes to the CSS just for clarity but you could update to your classes.

I added some color and things just for clarity and visual references but kept the "position relate" in separate CSS chunks.

```css
.main {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "box";
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main *,
.main::before {
  grid-area: box;
}

.green-block {
  place-self: start;
}

.red-block {
  width: 50%;
  place-self: end start;
}

.blue-block {
  width: 50%;
  place-self: end end;
}

.green-block {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: green;
}

.red-block {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue-block {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue-block,
.green-block,
.red-block {
  /* color for clarity and just to super center the text in the blocks */
  display: grid;
  color: cyan;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="div green-block">green</div>
    <div class="div1 red-block">red</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2 blue-block">blue</div>
</div>
```